# Deploying Private Repository using Vercel

Tags: git, github, repository, vercel

I'm still new to deploying apps/web apps.
Just wanted to confirm if will I be able build and deploy a Github private repo using Vercel?
I'm going to try if ever there would be a way as I'm still hesitant to use it in an existing deployed repo and make it private. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### New Update

It's been a couple of months Vercel now supports **Private Repositories** from the user's GitHub.

### Edited:

Since Vercel doesn't support private GitHub repositories for whatever reasons, you can still deploy private GIT repos using BitBucket.
See the details here: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git#deploying-private-git-repositories

Thanks to 
[Lucas Basquerotto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850646/lucas-basquerotto) for that information

---

Unfortunately, Vercel does not support private git repositories. If you want to deploy a private repo, you have to make it public first. However, you can deploy projects directly from your machine using the Vercel CLI.

For more information, you can go through [this](https://vercel.com/docs/deployments/overview) documentation.

Comment: I don't see any reference about not being able to deploy a private repository, neither in the link you posted nor elsewhere. There's even a section in their docs about private repositories (https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git#deploying-private-git-repositories). Actually, I just deployed a private bitbucket git repository. One thing, tough, is that Vercel wasn't able to "see" the private repositories that I had read (or write) access if I'm not the owner. Instead, I had to fork the repository and become the owner, and then I used the forked repository instead of the original.

Comment: Could you kindly describe in detail? If I have a private repo, then I'm the owner obviously. But when I try to import my personal private repo, Vercel couldn't find it. I tried with 'Import third-party git repo' option but it shows an error.

Comment: I used the normal option (not the third party) yesterday and i worked. I used Bitbucket, after the login with Bitbucket, it showed the workspaces that I have, I choose the one in which I had my repositories and it showed them (those that are in the form `/your-name/your-repo`, not those that are in the form `/some-other-name/some-repo`, belonging to another user or organisation, even if I have admin access to the repository). Just make sure you select the correct Bitbucket workspace in the dropdown (if it's a Github repo I assume the steps are similar, but have not tried).

Comment: I followed as you said. It worked perfectly with private repos in BitBucket but It didn't work for GitHub. Could you please try it with GitHub? I couldn't do that. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: I don't have a private repository at github, tough :/ You could explain your issue at https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions and see if someone there can solve for you.

Comment: Thanks so much...

Comment: This answer seems wrong. Vercel does support private github repos, but you need to select which repos vercel can access. See @AWIXOR's answer

Comment: @kimbaudi, when I answered that question, Vercel didn't support private GitHub repos. Check the date, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

You can deploy private repositories if you go to `profile > settings > application > vercel`, this is the link : [Github applications](https://github.com/settings/installations)

And add your repo under the `Repository access`.

Now you can find the repo listed in your `vercel profile`.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.  Vercel supports private GitHub repositories and I just had to add my private repo under Repository access.

Comment: mm, im lost, I dont the "respostitory access" to add to

Answer (score 1):

Now we can deploy Github private repo with vercel cli aslo, from your workspace.

Note - **If you just wanted to validate the changes from your local this is the right way to deploy. It's always recommended to sync your github repo with your latest commit.**

Step 1. download and install vercel

```
 npm i -g vercel
```

Step 2. Link your working directory vercel project
vc link
This would provide few setup instruction to connect to your vercel account.
[image]

Step 3. Now you can deploy your code to vercel with

```
  vc deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

--HOW TO DEPLOY PRIVATE GITHUB REPO ON VERCEL--

Navigate to your project in your system

1. First need to install Vercel globally using

> npm i -g vercel

2. Then run the command

> vc deploy

3. Vercel ask some question like.. do you want link multiple projects say [y/n] etc